# Date Binding in TextBox in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a ListView and in it there is a field with some date coming from the database. Now when I click on the Edit button, in the next Edit Page I want to show the exact date in the particular date field.

See the following screenshots:

Main View:

[image]

After clicking:

[image]

I have written the following code to bind the date:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FirstVisitDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' ID="FirstVisitDate" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="date" />
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Are you getting any error here ?. What's your Edit link button code. You should show us those codes.

Comment: @gkrishy i am not getting any error, I am just passing the corresponding element id using the querystring value and bind it with the list view on the edit page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one instead of yours:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" 
             Text='<%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Eval("FirstVisitDate")) %>' 
             ID="FirstVisitDate" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="date" />
```

If you are still getting error you can convert it to DateTime see if it works:

> ```
>  Text='<%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("FirstVisitDate")) %>'
> ```

also we don't have TextMode="date" ?? remove that one as well.

You could also try this way, which is way better than Eval in terms of performance:

> ```
> Text='<%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["FirstVisitDate"] %>'
> ```

if you want to show the format of the date, you should use placeholder instead like this:
also you could use type as a date like below:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="date" ... />
```

Comment: Hey I've used your code, it is showing the following error:

"CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: what is the data type for the FirstVisitDate ? is it DateTime ?

Comment: Yes the data type is DateTime

Comment: Try with Eval, see how it goes.

Comment: I have changed my code as it yours, now there is no error, but nothing is happening, it is still showing the same as the screenshot shows above

Comment: take the TextMode="date" as well

Comment: When i remove the date, the selected date is coming on the textbox. This is fine, but how can i apply the textmode and your code.

Comment: The last code of yours shows an error: "The best overload method match for 'string.this[int]' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: There are only three value for the Textmode property, which are Single multiline and password, there is no such a password for that, there was one bracket missing on the second code as well

Comment: After editing my code, when i click on the edit button it is showing the Compilation Error: "CS1026: ) expected"

Comment: I am using the Web Forms template and there are 16 values defined for the TextMode.

Comment: instead of TextMode use type="date"

Comment: Still same, no error. How about the Compilation Error: "CS1026: ) expected"??

Comment: @NimitJoshi The error is self-explaining. It is expecting a closing-bracket. So use this code `Text='<%# String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("FirstVisitDate"))) %>' `

Comment: This code is also working. But when the TextMode property is date, this code is not working. I think it is not possible. Thanks for giving the time to me.

Answer (score 0):

When using TextMode="date" you should always use the format yyyy-MM-dd ([W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value))

```
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("data", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")%>' runat="server" ID="dataTextBox" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control"/>
```